# Unbeaten classification dataset?

Tags: classification, dataset

Looking for a dataset that meets the following criteria:

- `Multi-class`, 3+ labels, preferably not binary.
- `Tabular` data, not images.
- Getting above `65-85%` prediction accuracy is a challenge. In general, high prediction accuracy would be seen as a struggle.

I am hoping to prove some potentially novel classification methods. To date, I have been working with the classic Iris, Abalone, Sonar, and Kaggle Zoo datasets - while scouring Kaggle for more.

Anyone know of a toughie? Even if it is your own data.

Comment: I have some problems in mind but their toughness mostly come from being unbalanced problems. Basically, in health (like cancer prediction), or credit risk (corporate default prediction). Would you be interested ?

Comment: @icrmorin Definitely - thank you. More inclined toward the loans due to the complexity of the biology behind cancer. Is there a git repo you could invite me to? I am about a month away from finishing the new model, which is why I am starting to seek data now.